# A modal in Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, dashboard

Is there a way to build self-opening modal in dashboard only for authors every time they are logging in admin area? How can I do that?

UPD. That's I'm trying:

```
    add_action('admin_footer', 'welcome_user');
    function welcome_user ()
    {
        add_thickbox(); ?>
        <a id="autoloadmodal" href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=my-content-id" class="thickbox"></a>
        <div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
            <p>
                Hello.
            </p>
        </div>
<?php if (!current_user_can('create_users')) { ?>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('autoloadmodal').click();
            //console.log('click');
        </script>
<?php } ?>
    <?php }
```

But no modal is shown.

Comment: Yes it can be done, what have you tried? You need to demonstrate that you've made an effort and tell us what didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the admin_init add action:

```
<?php 
  add_action('admin_init', 'open_modal');

  function open_modal(){ 
      $id = get_current_user_id()
      $user = get_userdata($id);
      if(in_array('author', $user->roles)){
  ?>

    <script>
      function call_to_open_modal(){
        //your code goes here...
      }

      call_to_open_modal();
    </script>

 <?php } } ?>
```

I used an inline js code to show, otherwise I could use wp_enqueue_script instead.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! So I'm trying to call thickbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script that Anthony has posted, and enqueue your modal CSS and JavaScript as normal but making sure you use the `is_admin()` conditional to load this only in the WordPress admin rather than the front-end.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin